# Why can't my Win32 program draw more than once?

Tags: api, winapi, visual-c++, draw, paint

I am trying to make a program that detects a key press and draws the corresponding letter on the window. Everything works fine but it only draws once... when I press another key nothing happens.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
{ 
   if (GetKeyState(0x41))
   {
      pCtrl->Paint (65);
   }
```

The Paint function calls a Char function which draws a character using `::Textout`
All I cannot understand is why doesn't it draw more than once

Comment: I bet each character is draw at the same location.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to answer without the code to Paint but I think you are approaching the problem incorrectly. Win32 applications should only modify their display area when handling the WM_PAINT message. When the WM_KEYDOWN message is received it should use InvalidateRect() to invalidate the display and let the application repaint itself. To remove the inevitable flicker, the WM_KEYDOWN handler could record the type of change and the WM_PAINT handler could only update the display that character is shown.